# Sharepoint custom fields and SPFieldMultiColumnValue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to study custom fields in SharePoint.Can anyone help me to study the SPFieldMultiColumnValue specified below.

```
    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();

            SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = new SPFieldMultiColumnValue(2);
            mcv[0] = txtDurationId.Text;
            mcv[1] = DDLDurationID.SelectedValue;

            return mcv;
        }
        set
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();

            SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = (SPFieldMultiColumnValue)this.ItemFieldValue;
            txtDurationId.Text = mcv[0];
            DDLDurationID.SelectedValue = mcv[1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what do you want to do here, so not possible to "study" the scenario you posted here, Maybe ask what you trying to do and what have you achieved to far